# Ejecutar Procedure con parámetro de entrada y cursor de salida

Tags: oracle, plsql

Estoy con ORACLE 12 
Tengo un Procedure que basicamente me devuelve un SELECT, con un cursor, fitrando por un campo.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_permiso(DESCR IN PERMISO.DESCRIPCION%TYPE, 
  cursor_ OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
BEGIN
OPEN cursor_ FOR
      SELECT ID   
      FROM PERMISO WHERE DESCRIPCION = DESCR; 
END;
```

El problema es que no puedo ejecutarlo

Ejecución

```
VAR x REFCURSOR;
EXEC get_permiso('macro2', :x);
PRINT :x;
```

Error

> ORA-06550: línea 1, columna 7: PLS-00306: número o tipos de argumentos
>   erróneos al llamar a 'GET_PERMISO' ORA-06550: línea 1, columna 7:
>   PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Añado a esto, que desde C# si puedo acceder al mismo, y los resultados son correctos.

Llamada C#

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dbManager.OpenConnection();
            List<OracleParameter> ls = new List<OracleParameter>
            {
                new OracleParameter
                {

                    OracleDbType = OracleDbType.NVarchar2,
                    Size=500,
                    ParameterName = "DESCR",
                    DbType = DbType.String,
                    Value = "Dashboard.DoSomething",
                    Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
                },
                new OracleParameter
                {

                    OracleDbType = OracleDbType.RefCursor,
                    ParameterName = "cursor_",
                    Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
                }
            };

            OracleCommand myCommand = (OracleCommand)dbManager.CreateCommand("get_permiso", ls);
            OracleDataAdapter adapt = new OracleDataAdapter(myCommand);
            adapt.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            adapt.Fill(dt);
```

Comment: En tu `select`, necesitas devolver un dato que se encuentra en el cursor???

Comment: Si, el select debe devolver los datos mencionados.

Comment: que parametro ingresas en `cursor_ OUT SYS_REFCURSOR` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes intentar de esta forma(debes editar el tipo de dato de la variable `id_new`):

```
        CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_permiso(DESCR IN PERMISO.DESCRIPCION%TYPE, 
                  cursor_ OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
                IS
                BEGIN

                  declare id_new INT (30);


                OPEN cursor_ FOR
                      SELECT ID   
                      FROM PERMISO; 

                open cursor_;

                 bucle: loop

                      fetch cursor_ into id_new;
                        if (no_hay_mas_registros = 1) then
                            leave bucle;
                        end if;


                SELECT ID FROM PERMISO WHERE DESCRIPCION = DESCR and ID=id_new; 



                    end loop bucle;
                  close elCursor;


                END;
```